# What is the best way to escape user output with the Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm a little confused by what I should use to escape user output.

Firstly, there's the [`Zend_Filter_Input`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html) class which looks like it might do what I want but seems oriented towards batch filtering lots of items. At the moment I only want to filter one. Also I'm a little confused by the definition of escapers compared to filters. What's the difference between the `StringTrim` filter and the escaper?

Is there a better solution for escaping single elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filters are great on your forms so that you can clean & normalize your data before processing/storing it.  You mentioned StringTrim - you've got other ones that ensure capitalization or that your input is all numeric (or alphanumeric or...).  Make a note that this is to ensure consistency and sanity in your data - not for avoiding SQL injection - ZF's Database libraries handle that as a separate issue.

On the flip-side of this, you get to escape things for output.  While "x < 5" or "PB&J" may be perfectly valid data to store and process in your system, they can cause problems when displayed on a web page.  This is why you'd normally use `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` - by default, Zend_View uses htmlspecialchar() when you `$this->escape($foo)`.

Comment: Thank you - I didn't know about the escape view helper.

Answer (score 1):

Use [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars)?

If this is not what you want, please specify what you mean by "escape user output".

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about security and want to automatically escape all variables similar to how Django does then you might be interested in this article.

[How to automatically escape template variables in Zend_View](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2007/11/10/how-to-automatically-escape-template-variables-in-zend_view/)